# need to pass a default emailid in azure active directory authentication

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am doing Azure Active Directory authentication and using openidconnect for authentication. My application has it own login page and I am trying to redirect the user as soon as they type user id in my login page.

But I am unable to pass userid from my login page to azure login page. I am using following code for 
calling azure login page and it redirected correctly but I am not able to pass any default login id which should be displayed on the azure login page like "abc@microsoft.com".

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a login_hint query string parameter in the redirect to the authorization server. Here is a post which describes this (in the context of Google login, which also uses OpenID Connect):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1999402.aspx?Owin+pass+custom+query+parameters+in+Authentication+Request

In your case, I suggest you try the following:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/",
        Dictionary =
        {
            { "login_hint", "abc@microsoft.com" }
        }
    });
```